# numberOfRowsInTableView is not being called

Tags: xcode, methods, nstableview

I'm setting up a view-based NSTableView, however the method numberOfRowsInTableView is not being called. When I check whether it is being called, the log returns nil.

I have set up my AppDelegate to conform to the datasource and the delegate protocols and have connected these through IB to the AppDelegate. My array that will feed the table is initialised when app finishes loading.

My code is as follows:

Interface

```
#import <Cocoa/Cocoa.h>

@interface RLTAppDelegate : NSObject <NSApplicationDelegate, NSTableViewDataSource, NSTableViewDelegate>

@property (assign) IBOutlet NSWindow *window;
@property (weak) IBOutlet NSTableView *tableView;
@property (copy) NSArray *nameArray;

@end
```

Implementation

```
#import "RLTAppDelegate.h"

@implementation RLTAppDelegate

- (void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(NSNotification *)aNotification
{
  self.nameArray = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"Ryan", nil];
}

- (NSInteger)numberOfRowsInTableView:(NSTableView *)tableView {

  return [self.nameArray count];
  NSLog(@"%lu", self.nameArray.count);
}

- (NSView *)tableView:(NSTableView *)tableView
   viewForTableColumn:(NSTableColumn *)tableColumn
              row:(NSInteger)row {

NSTextField *result = [tableView makeViewWithIdentifier:@"name" owner:self];
result.stringValue = [self.nameArray objectAtIndex:row];
return result;
}

@end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just made a test project to see what is going on.

If you put a breakpoint on `applicationDidFinishLaunching` and also on `numberOfRowsInTableView` you'll see that the `numberOfRowsInTableView` method is called before the `applicationDidFinishLaunching` notification is received.

So you're asking for the array before it has been populated.

Normally, you'd have a separate class where this happens and you set up the array when that class in initialised, so this doesn't happen.

Comment: He is correct, and since you are logging with a string with just an operator it will not log it in the console if the object is nil

Comment: You're a lifesaver. I guess I need to split out my model class and have that populate first before then sending the result to the array.

Comment: @TeenDev Yea, I saw that happening (or not). Thanks for pointing it out!